# No Values Return While Calling stored Procedure with Parameters

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, datagridview

I have made one stored procedure which is as follows:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[newjoins]
@GIVNO as nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
select  * from  GIV where GIVNO=@GIVNO
END
```

and try to call this procedure from VB.Net code as follows:-

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("newjoins")
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GIVNO", TextBox1.Text)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

But i am getting nothing in the datagridview. If i make a procedure without any parameters then values displayed in datagridview but with Parameters nothing happend. Please help me to solve this issue.
Regards

Comment: If you are getting results without a `WHERE` clause and nothing with a `WHERE` clause then the problem is with data matching the clause - are you sure you have data to match your query?

Comment: Yes absolutely. For example, in GIVNo column in database values are like this GIVNo001, GIVNo002... So when i enter GIVNo001 in TextBox1 then i should get the result but nothing return.

Comment: Have you tried executing the Stored Procedure directly on the database (like using Management Studio)?

Comment: Yes in Managemet studio query excuted succefully. values are not showing their either because there is parameter. I also go to stored procedure in visual studio when execute, one parameter box popup. i enter parameter value is accepted but no value return in output .

Comment: Two things - 1. Remove the `@` sign from the VB.Net code in the line: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GIVNO", TextBox1.Text)` as it is not necessary.

Comment: 2. Check that the parameter you enter in the text box exactly matches, check the case and for trailing/leading spaces

Comment: Stop using .AddWithValue in Sql Server.

Comment: i comply all above coments but no luck. i got error instead if remove withvalue convert from string "GIV0001"to type integer is not valid. i used dbtype nvarchar as it is in database. As per comments i dont see any mistake pointed out in my code. i think something wrong with Visual studio.

Comment: @TalatFarooq did you make a typo when entering `GIV0001`as it is not the same as `GIVo001`

Comment: No bro. It just an example i am entering correct parameters. But i dont know why i am not getting values when using parameters. This is becoming a milllion dollar question.

Comment: Finally,  i got it. The variable should be declared like this @GIVNO as nvarchar (50)